# How to track the incoming and outgoing traffic for specific app?

Tags: networking

I would like to see what URLs and all the internet traffic is processing for a specific application on Windows 10.

I've downloaded an executable app, and it requires to have a stable permanent internet connection. I believe it sends some requests (kind of polling) to check whether I'm allowed to do some specific tasks.

Is there some free tool for that ?

Something similiar to what Google Chrome Dev Tool offers.

[image]

Comment: I use Comm View (Tamosoft) for this. Wireshark might help and it is free.

Comment: Wireshark is one of the most mature and capable tools for this.